# Should expression evaluation depend on the choice of a variable name?

Tags: evaluation, special-functions, summation, letter-makes-difference

I am verifying the series representation of the Sonine polynomial or the associated Laguerre polynomial, which is

$$
L_m^{(n)}(x)=\sum\limits_{l=0}^n\left(-1\right)^l\binom{m+n}{m-l}\frac{x^l}{l!}=S_{n}^{(m)}(x)
$$

In this process, I found that name of the variable can affect the calculation results, which means

```
Sum[(Gamma[n+m+1](-x)^l)/(l!(n-l)!Gamma[l+m+1]),{l,0,n}]
```

and

```
Sum[(Gamma[n+m+1](-x)^p)/(p!(n-p)!Gamma[p+m+1]),{p,0,n}]
```

will give different results.

[image]

I wonder why this happens. Is

Comment: They are the same mathematically speaking. Screen shot: ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcl0u.png)  as to why the letter used makes difference, this came up before many times. Internally there is some lexicographical ordering, which causes different code path to be taken somewhere. it is annoying ofcourse. see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/264589/apart-behaves-differently-depending-on-specific-alphabetic-letters-of-variables) as one example. There are more....

Comment: .... and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/124159/integral-depends-on-choice-of-symbols)

Comment: We really need to make a new tag called **letter_used_makes_difference** so it is easy to find such posts later on, as it is now hard to find these in this forum by just googling.

Comment: @Nasser Why not? Let's add it. I'm tired of searching for such posts, too. :D

Answer (score 1):

Of course, many formulas, that cannot be derived by algorithmical methods - characteristically all forms of Eulers hypergeometric series - are solved by table lookup, corrected by Wolframs work, to verify the tables by numerical approximations, series expansion  and algebraical verification methods.

I remember to have read in the first times of CAS invention, that about 15% of all table formulas contain errors.

From the following you see, that general formulas for hypergeometric functions are using different table entries  for values of te the summation character from a-k and o-z.

Since this is a local, integer summation variable, the results, depending on its character, show a badly coded table lookup in the sense: ?all symbols from the integer part of the alphabet i,j,k,l,m,n ?.

```
         ff = Function[{a}, 
             Sum[(Gamma[n + m + 1] (-x)^a)/
                 (a! (n - a)!  Gamma[a + m + 1]), 
                 {a, 0, n}]]

         (# -> ff[#] &) /@ 
            Symbol /@ (Cases[CharacterRange["a", "z"], 
                             Except["l" | "m" | "n" | "x"]]) // TableForm
```

$$a \dots k \to \frac{\Gamma (m+n+1) \, _1F_1(-n;m+1;x)}{\Gamma (m+1) \Gamma (n+1)}$$
$$o \dots z  \to L[n, m, x]$$

If the formula is not textual 1-1 with the definition of the Laguerre polynomial, the general identification as a hypergeometric series from the recurrence formmula of the coefficients in the Taylor series is used.

Mathematica cannot identify the results. There are still large fields open to research for transforms of special function expressions into eachother by an CAS.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of, is that WL sorts sums and multiplications because of the `Orderless` attribute. You can easily see this when you just let it evaluate the bodies of the two sums:

[image]

Note the factor `l! (-l + n)!` in the first output and `(n - p)! p!` in the second because `l` comes before `n` while `p` comes after. I'm guessing that this difference somehow cascades to the different results, probably during a pattern matching step. It's undesirable, but this is my guess for what's going on.

Comment: This is part of the issue. The next part is that intermediate simplifications applied by `Sum` and the like can have different outcomes.